# shortest path between two vertices after adding two new edges in a graph

Tags: graph, distance, shortest

Given a weighted(Positive weights) undirected graph G(V,E)...we are given two vertices s,t belongs to V. we have to find two new edges from a list of available edges((a1,b1)...(ak,bk)) to add to tha graph such that the distance between s and t is minimised as much as possible. The weights of new edges are all positive as well..

the direct approach would be two select all possible pairs of new edges and find shortest distance with it. the time complexity for this approach is quadratic k. i want an algorithm with better time complexity .. please help me on this ..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful edge must shorten the distance between its vertices.

```
LOOP over K
  Find S shortest path between ak and bk in G
  IF new edge weight is greater or equal, discard (ak,bk)
APPLY direct algorithm on remaining available edges.
```

Comment: what if all the new edge weights are less than shortest path between ak and bk ... so what happens then? I didnt understand whats the use of looping over k ?

Comment: even after looping over k .. lets say i take two edges that are less than S . Now how will i know these are the two edges that i have to add to the graph so that distance between s and t will be minimised.There's a possibility that inital shortest path doesnt go through these vertices ..

Comment: " how will i know these are the two edges that i have to add"  last step of the algorithm, apply direct algorithm on reduced list of available edges.

Comment: what will be the time complexity of this ?isnt it still quadratic ??

Comment: The point is that even just one available edge is removed, the direct algorithm will run significantly faster.  In graphs that model something in the real world, most of the of the new edges will be discarded and the direct algorithm will run very much faster.

Comment: ok .. thanks for the solution .. much appreciated..